# Visual Studio 2010 Database Projects: Are there any videos/tutorials or comments about the new Database Project Types?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2010. I have kept database projects separate to application projects. The database project was converted from and old DPR project and added a whole lot of additional folder. I deleted those, but now I suspect I need to recreate the project as these new projects work very differently.

Now that I have need to update scripts, it seems I cant even paste new SQL files into the project so am a bit stuck. Are there any tutorials / walkthrough that show the basics on starting and creating a database project? Or even better a video?

Also if there are any tips and tricks or comments on this, I will be happy to hear them?

Comment: I assume question is in the right place as it about programming databases and the programming environment?

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/02/vs-2010-database-project-an-introduction.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft's [tutorials and walk-throughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty(VS.100).aspx) gave me what I needed to get started.

Comment: Thanks for that...the projects are diffenent animals, but definately look productive...

Answer (score 1):

I just did the same thing a few days ago and noticed that the Database Projects in 2010 are somewhat different from the one you could install onto 2008 with a GDR (R2). Not only some folders have changed but also some controls on property pages have been updated.

I decided to do it clean. I recreated the project in 2010 and just copied the stuff from the old project. Everything is working fine.

Comment: I can only seem to paste existing files into the disk folders and "Include in Project" or Add existing items from the menu's. It seems copy and paste does'nt work, which is a realy pain?

Comment: I haven't tried to copy directly in project tree. I also copied files on disk and added them as existing items. I think it's okay this way. You only do it once... well, until the next version of VS is out.

Comment: After a new table is created, I use code generation to generate stored procedures and used to just dropped those into the database project. It's not a biggy but is an extra step...arrrgh

Comment: I am assuming its because the files require additional properties... Although it may not be a good idea to automatically "Include in Build" for dropped in files I am sure Visual studio could have safe default and optional behaviour...